# Nativescript how to make a if condition in View XML

Tags: nativescript

Is there anyway to do a if condition in the XML file of nativescript? (without angular)

```
if

<Card:CardView class="cardStyle" margin="10" elevation="40" radius="5">
  <Slider value="18" minValue="5" maxValue="30" />
</Card:CardView>

else

<Card:CardView class="cardStyle" margin="10" elevation="40" radius="5">
  <Label text="Example" class="h3" margin="10" />
</Card:CardView>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is use a boolean [property](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/properties) (which in its get function has the condition you want) and bind it to the visibility of the `CardView`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can show/hide from the template file using visibility:

In XML file: ie. '**sample-page.xml**'

```html
<Button text="{{ isShowing ? 'Hide Me' : 'Show Me' }}" tap="toggleShowing"/> <!-- Notice missing interpolation in Button tag -->
<Label text="Showing Hidden Element" visibility="{{ isShowing ? 'visible' :  'collapsed' }}"/>
```

In Page file: ie. '**sample-page.ts**'

> let model = new ViewModel();
>
> // Event handler for Page 'loaded' event attached in main-page.xml
>   export function pageLoaded(args: observable.EventData) {
>
> ```
>  const page = <Page>args.object;
>  page.bindingContext = model;
> ```
>
> }
>
> export function toggleShowing() {
>
> ```
>  model.set('isShowing', !model.get('isShowing'));
> ```
>
> }

In View Model: ie. '**sample-view-model.ts**'

> isShowing:boolean = false;

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to do to do this was to use the navigatingTo event of the page:

```
export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    let page = <Page>args.object;
    var myLayout = <StackLayout>page.getViewById("myLayout");
        if (condition) {
            let segmentedBar = new SegmentedBar;  
            ...
            myLayout.addChild(segmentedBar);
        }
        else {
            let button: Button = new Button;
            ...
            myLayout.addChild(button);
        }
```

No possibility in the template file :-/

Comment: Interesting, it looks about right. I'll definitely give it a try

Answer (score -1):

It can be done using ng-container.For example
`<ng-container *ngIf="true">Your logic here....</ng-container>`